# Facebook Photo Albums

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a small php code to post random images onto my facebook page, the random images are posted correctly to facebook but after a while the posts are removed and grouped into a single post saying that 'My user name has posted a new photo to album xyz' and of course any friend can access the album from this post to view all the photos

I don't want the photos to be grouped into a single post but rather keep each photo in its own post, is this something that I can configure in facebook or that I can control from my php code?

Thanks

Comment: No, that is nothing you can control

Comment: Facebook feature.. bundle photos within a period of time into one single story on Timeline

Comment: What about adding all the photos yo the album and then use the graph api to post them onto the wall or refer to them from the wall, does the graph api support this? Do you know how to write this code?